# Azure App service (Linux Nginx) file upload error 413 (Payload Too Large)

Tags: linux, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I am getting  413 (Payload Too Large) when I try to upload a video with size 10MB. How can I change the app service upload size.

Server:Azure App service (Linux Nginx)
API: PHP 8

I tried adding client_max_body_size 100M;didn't work

[image]

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming or software development and therefore is not a good fit for SO... Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: [Search is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+413)

Comment: Also: does this answer your question? [Azure App Service Returning 413 Payload Too Large on Long POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70071422/azure-app-service-returning-413-payload-too-large-on-long-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to modify the client_max_body_size directive in the nginx configuration file. The location of the configuration file is:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

add or edit the following setting:

client_max_body_size 100M;

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work for me. I updated my question with what I did

Comment: I am struggling with this same issue.  Where do you put the "client_max_body_size 100M;" line?  there is no http block in the nginx.conf file for the Azure web app.  There is only a server block.  I've tried putting that line in various places to no effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66777762/1384539